# What is the difference between a Dialog and a Conversation in Microsoft Bot Framework?

Tags: .net, bots, botframework, azure-language-understanding

For me personally a Dialog and a Conversation is the same thing. However the framework differentiates between these two terms and I do not quite understand what the difference is. Also I cannot find an exact, understandable definiton somewhere in the docs.

Comment: This is a valid question about specific terms with a new framework. To close this as "broad" one should have experience with that framework and be *certain* that the two terms aren't actual technical terms or features

Comment: In fact, I think that in natural language/speech processing, a conversation is open-ended while a dialog is well-defined, eg the annoying voice response systems of banks. I think the distinction was explicit in the Windows Speech API as well

Answer (score 2):

The overview for the [C# Dialogs documentation](http://docs.botframework.com/sdkreference/csharp/dialogs.html) explains pretty well the concepts:

> **Dialogs model a conversational process**, where the exchange of messages between bot and user is the primary channel for interaction with the outside world. **Each dialog is an abstraction that encapsulates its own state in a C# class that implements IDialog**. Dialogs can be composed with other dialogs to maximize reuse, and a dialog context maintains a stack of dialogs active in the conversation. **A conversation composed of dialogs is portable across machines to make it possible to scale a bot implementation**. This conversation state (the stack of active dialogs and each dialog's state) is stored in the messages exchanged with the Bot Connector, making the bot implementation stateless between requests. (Much like a web application that does not store session state in the web server's memory.)

Also, from the [Dialogs Node.js documentation](http://docs.botframework.com/builder/node/dialogs/overview/#navtitle):

> **To understand dialogs its easiest to think of them as the equivalent
>   of routes for a website**. All bots will have at least one root ‘/’
>   dialog just like all websites typically have at least one root ‘/’
>   route. When the framework receives a message from the user it will be
>   routed to this root ‘/’ dialog for processing.

Comment: 1. So basically one Dialog always represents one "topic"? For example questions regarding cars would be a CarDialog. Questions regarding food would be FoodDialog and all these dialogs can be combined? 2. "A conversation composed of dialogs is portable across machines to make it possible to scale a bot implementation" => does that mean you can use it with Skype, etc.? 3. "This conversation state is stored in the messages..." => so ALL the messages in one conversation are in that DialogState field (some encrypted value??)

Comment: 1) It will depend on how you code them. Nothing prevent you for having a dialog doing Car and Food stuff. The Dialog is just an interface (http://docs.botframework.com/sdkreference/csharp/dd/d5e/interface_microsoft_1_1_bot_1_1_builder_1_1_dialogs_1_1_i_dialog.html) you have to implement. 3) Yes, this conversation state (the stack of active dialogs and each dialog's state) is stored in the messages exchanged with the Bot Connector, making the bot implementation stateless between requests. (Much like a web application that does not store session state in the web server's memory.)

Comment: Regarding 2) I would say that statement refers to since the dialogs are serializables then it's portable and allows you to scale

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However I still do not quite understand when to create different dialogs.The docs don't help me in this case. I need an example, like... foreach Entity in a class diagram you create a new class in .NET for the Entity Framework.

Comment: Right, there's isn't a rule like in EF. Your dialog receive a message, and you do things with the message received. Your root dialog can start child dialogs if that message can't be handled by it. The easiest example could be a dialog that do stuff but that needs the user to be authenticated. So the root dialog will check if the user has a token and if not start the authdialog. Let's do it on the other way. What do you want your bot to do?

Comment: Our bot is actually quite simple. We want to create an online shop. First, the bot asks for a product, then asks for a delivery address which all should be extracted through LUIS. We thought Dialog Chains are they key to success but sadly we haven't found a suitable solution. The same thing counts for Forms. Also we have found no way to use LuisIntents with the options mentioned above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116677/discussion-between-ejadib-and-mark).